# JPA Entity Lifecycle Events @PostUpdate transaction commit occurs at different time

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three entities in my application one parameter of which depends on the value of Building entity. Parameter `type` is dependent on the value of parameter `endDate` of Building entity. CustomType is an entity stored in another schema of the db.

I understand that this usage of JPA callback is probably breaking conventions and we already have the idea how to implement this other way, but my curiosity won't let me drop this case: what is the cause of different behaviour of Hibernate in those two situations?

I decided to update parameters of Stage and Project via JPA lifecycle event and implemented @PrePersist, @PostUpdate and @PostPersist listeners. This is when I encountered the problem: we are using JSON API to save our entities without explicitly writing code to do so. But for the operation of soft deletion we are using custom RestController, which is saving entity via JPA Repository `save()` method. When JPA Events are triggered by JSON API everything works correctly - CustomType is changed in all of the entities and persisted to the database. When we are deleting entity and causing changes in type - @PostUpdate callback is working in unexpected way. It seems to persist changes only in Building entity, completely ignoring Stage and Project. After checking via EntityManager.contains() - they are in managed state in the method that is inside of JPA @PostUpdate event, so I expected same behaviour - persist changes without explicitly calling to save() method.

Building.java

```
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "BUILDING", schema = "---")
@EntityListeners(BuildingListener.class)
@Where(clause = "DELETED = 0")
public class Building extends BaseEntity {

    String name;
    String description;
    Date endDate;
    Project project;
    Stage stage;
    CustomType type;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   @Column(name = "END_DATE")
    public Date getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STAGE_ID")
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE")
    public CustomType getType(){
        return type;
    }
```

Project.java

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "PROJECT", schema = "---")
@Where(clause = "DELETED = 0")
public class Project extends BaseEntity {

    String name;
    String description;
    List<Stage> stages;
    List<Building> buildings;
    CustomType type;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    public List<Stage> getStages() {
        return stages;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    public List<Building> getBuildings() {
        return buildings;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE")
    public CustomType getType(){
        return type;
    }
```

Stage.java

```
@ToString(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "PROJECT", schema = "---")
@Where(clause = "DELETED = 0")
public class Stage extends BaseEntity {

    String name;
    String description;
    Project project;
    List<Building> buildings;
    CustomType type;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

   @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
    public List<Building> getBuildings() {
        return buildings;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TYPE")
    public CustomType getType(){
        return type;
    }
```

BuildingListener.java

```
    
    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Building building){
        listenerService.checkTypeForNewBuilding(building);
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void prePersist(Building building){
        listenerService.checkTypeForExistingBuilding(building);
    }
    
    @PostUpdate
    @PostPersist
    public void post(Building building){
        listenerService.resolveTypesForRelations(building);
    }
}
```

ListenerService.java

```
    public void checkTypeForNewBuilding(Building building){
        CustomType type1 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        CustomType type2 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        if (/*logic*/){
            building.setType(type1);
        } else{
            building.setType(type2);
        }
    }

    public void checkTypeForExistingBuilding(Building building){
        CustomType type1 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        CustomType type2 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        if (/*logic*/){
            building.setType(type1);
        } else{
            building.setType(type2);
        }
    }

    public void resolveTypesForRelations(Building building){
        CustomType type1 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        CustomType type2 = CustomType.builder().id(/*typeId here*/);
        Project project = building.getProject();
        Stage stage = building.getStage();
        if (/*logic*/){
            project.setType(type1);
            stage.setType(type1);
        } else{
            project.setType(type2);
            stage.setType(type2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what it is exactly that is unexpected. The listener has the method parameter type `Building`. Hibernate can't call these methods for entities that aren't a subtype of that.

Comment: Unexpected behaviour occurs in ListenerService - when we persist new Building entity or update parameters - my logic for changing CustomType works correctly and changes of CustomType are persisted in other entities. 
When we are deleting our entity (although, in our case - it is soft deletion. so basically update) changes in other entity CustomTypes are not persisted to db even when explicitly calling save() method.

Right now I think the cause is the @Where annotation on entities

Comment: It's hard to help you here since you seem to have a lot of code involved here and your problem seems to be specific to your custom logic. I'd suggest you to provide a test application via GitHub so other people can execute that locally to help you.

Comment: Totally agree with you, it got out of hand with the amount of code. If I won't be able to resolve this issue by myself in a few days - I will update the question. Thanks for the response!